# StageVideoAvailabilityEvent not found

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, flash-builder, stagevideo

Im Working on Air Application and heres my Class

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageVideo;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;


public class presentation extends Sprite
{

    private const VIDEO_FILE_URL:String = "assets/Presentation_Demo_02.mp4";
    private var video:Video;
    private var stageVideo:StageVideo;
    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;
    private var streamClient:Object;
    public function presentation()
    {

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        //stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
    }

    private function init(event:Event):void
    {
        trace("All Works");
        initStream();


        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stageResize);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
    }

    private function initStream():void
    {
        streamClient = new Object();
        streamClient.onMetaData = onMetaData;

        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);

        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.client = streamClient;
        addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY,onChange);

    }
    private function onChange(event:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.availability);
    }

    private function stageResize(event:Event):void
    {


    }

    private function update(event:Event):void
    {


    }
    public function onMetaData(e:Object):void
    {}

}
}
```

on the line where addEventListener for StageVideoAvailabilityEvent i got Error in Flash Builder

> Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.

what can i do

Comment: What's the version of Flex that you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are using a version of Adobe AIR that supports StageVideo. (I recommend you to download the latest version, 17).
Update your Adobe AIR Application Description file to the respective AIR version. (in this case 17)

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0">
```

Also, be sure that you add an extra compiler argument to indicate the respective SWF version (fro AIR 17, should be 28:

```
-swf-version=28
```